# How to prove that in any triangle $ABC$, there exists a point $D$ on the longest side of the triangle, $BC$, such that $AD \perp BC$?

Tags: geometry, triangles

How to prove that in any triangle $ABC$, there exists a point $D$ on the longest side of the triangle, $\overline{BC}$, such that $\overline{AD} \perp \overline{BC}$, using only geometry.
[image: A triangle with longest side on BC]

I tried proving this by contradiction, by assuming that for every point $D$ on $\overline{BC}$, $\angle ADB>90\unicode{xB0}$ or $\angle ADB<90\unicode{xB0}$. Let $D$ be any point on $\overline{BC}$. For the first case, $\angle ADB>90\unicode{xB0}$, I've only managed to show that
$\angle DAB + \angle B < 90\unicode{xB0}$. I wish to show somehow show that $\angle A < \angle C$ or $\angle A < \angle B$, then I can show that $\overline{BC}$ isn't the longest side of the triangle. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd say, suppose the perpendicular from $A$ to $BC$ doesn't meet $BC$ but instead meets $BC$-extended at $D$. If $D$ is left of $B$, then $ADC$ is a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse (hence, longest side) $AC$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $BC$ is the longest side, we have $B,C<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Therefore, you can always draw a line $AD$ such that $\angle CAD=\frac{\pi}{2}-C$ and $\angle BAD=\frac{\pi}{2}-B$ like the following:

[image]

Since the sum of angles in a triangle must be $\pi$, we have $\angle CDA = \frac{\pi}{2}$, i.e., $AD\perp BC$